# where can I find openGL ES function implementation?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-x86

I downloaded android x86 from http://www.android-x86.org. But I cannot found how OpenGL API was implemented  there. In which file of this project( uncompiled) is implementation of functions? And how does it implement on android x86, because it is open source project, but I have read that implementation of API depends on vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "implementation"? If you mean to get the OpenGL driver source code then forget about it as it is not exposed by the vendors (except MESA).If you mean OpenGL API functions which usually are exposed by libraries like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) via header file then you should check how Android SDK acquires those methods.The methods are basically function address pointers.Android probably uses JNI to access those on the Java side via NDK.As Android uses OpenGL ES it means that the implementation is a part of the OS so you won't be able to dig into it exactly as you can not dig into OpenGL implementation of Nvidia graphics drivers.

Check [MESA](http://www.mesa3d.org/) if you want to get an idea how it looks like under the hood.